# The Windows Defender reporting PHP Backdoor

Tags: windows-10, php

I recently got a message from `Windows Defender` about a high risk level threat found on my system: `Backdoor:PHP/Dirtelti.MTE`. What's most strange is that the file to which the message applies is `php-7.4.8.tar.gz`.

Is it a real threat that I have to worry about? It refers to the file which I've downloaded from the official site for PHP server. If it is valid, would it be sufficient to just remove the `php-7.4.8.tar.gz` file from my system or have I to reinstall it to be sure I'm safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens from time to time, and for all Anti Virus suites, Defender included.

Open Windows Defender, go to Virus and Threat Protections, and then in the right hand screen, Allowed Threats and whitelist the app causing the issue.

As I note, somewhat normal to have to do this. You said you downloaded the file from an official source.

Comment: Perhaps a good idea to scan the file on Virustotal first to be sure, right? Or check the sha256 signature of the file?

Comment: You can do that and also a Full Scan, but the app above appears to be legitimate, so do whitelist it.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Oh... I've just told the Defender to delete the file. Is there a way to revert the file to scan the file on Virustotal?

Comment: You can perhaps download the file again?

Comment: @John. Txh for help. The another strange thing is that i've downloaded the file some time ago and it have been existing on my disk for some time now and why The Defender discovered the thread just now?

Comment: If you let Defender delete the file, you need to download it again. In Quarantine, you can allow it.  If it was valid before, it could be a change in Defender Signatures. Just be sure of your source.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Yeah, ok but i don't remember where exactly i've got the file form. I'm sure i've got it from some official, trusted site but i'm not sure which. Does The Defender removes the files permanently?

Comment: It only deletes permanently if you allow the action and delete it from the Quarantine. If you are not sure of the source (I thought you were), delete it, download fresh from a good source.

Comment: @John. So if it was valid before (wasn't discovered by Defender previously) can i make an assumption that i'm 100% safe and ignore that threat?

Comment: So long as you are reasonably sure of the source and it was fine before, then you should be able to safely allow the file.

Comment: @DarosRT10 perhaps you can go to the [php website](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) and look for a download there. Seems like a reasonable place to search.

Comment: Just a comment. I keep Cain and Abel in my files. Cain can expose an XP password in seconds with the right rainbow tables. 32-bit only. I went to the folder and Defender immediately picked it up (as it should) and I whitelisted it.

Comment: Ok, i've just downloaded the file again from official PHP site and The Defender is recognizing the file as a threat AGAIN! [There is](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.8.tar.gz) the link to the file.

Comment: Just whitelist the file and you should be fine.

Comment: The file whitelisted. Thx guys for help:-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this same message on this simple PHP Script:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("type convert"); 
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This is of course a potential problem and could be deployed to display unprotected server content.